# How to get value of LiveData from repository that don't access to lifeCycleOwner for observing it?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-room, android-viewmodel, android-livedata

I have used of `MVVM` and `ROOM` and `databindig` in my app.According 
[Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#fetching_data) ,I want to cash data using room.In the `xml` layout of `RecyclerView` item, I use `CategoryViewModel` variable.I get list of categories from `Room` database with`LiveData` type. I want to change `LiveData<list<CategoryItem>>` type to `MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CategoryViewModel>>` type. Because finally my adapter consume `ArrayList<CategoryViewModel>` data type.How to get value of `LiveData`? When I call `getValue()` method, returns null.
this is `CategoryItem` model:

```
    @Entity(tableName = "category_table")
public class CategoryItem implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String imagePath;
    @TypeConverters({SubCategoryConverter.class})
    private ArrayList<String> subCategory;
    @TypeConverters({DateConverter.class})
    private Date lastRefresh;

    public CategoryItem(int id, String title, String imagePath, ArrayList<String> subCategory, Date lastRefresh) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
        this.subCategory = subCategory;
        this.lastRefresh=lastRefresh;
    }

    public CategoryItem(int id, String title, String imagePath) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public CategoryItem() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imagePath;
    }

    public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
        this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getSubCategory() {
        return subCategory;
    }

    public void setSubCategory(ArrayList<String> subCategory) {
        this.subCategory = subCategory;
    }

    public Date getLastRefresh() {
        return lastRefresh;
    }

    public void setLastRefresh(Date lastRefresh) {
        this.lastRefresh = lastRefresh;
    }

}
```

this is `CategoryViewModel` class:

```
     public class CategoryViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

        private String title;
        private String imagePath;
        private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CategoryViewModel>> allCategories=new MutableLiveData<>();
        private CategoryRepository repository;

        public CategoryViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
            super(application);
            repository=new CategoryRepository(application, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
        }

        public void init(CategoryItem categoryItem){
            this.title=categoryItem.getTitle();
            this.imagePath=categoryItem.getImagePath();
        }

        public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CategoryViewModel>> getAllCategories(){

            allCategories=repository.getCategory();
            return allCategories;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getImagePath() {
            return imagePath;
        }
    }
```

This is `CategoryRepository` class:

```
    public class CategoryRepository {

    private static final String TAG="CategoryRepository";
    private static int FRESH_TIMEOUT_IN_MINUTES = 1;

    private final Executor executor;

    private APIInterface apiInterface;
    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CategoryViewModel>> arrayListMutableLiveData=new MutableLiveData<>();


    private CategoryDao categoryDao;
    private Application application;

    public CategoryRepository(Application application,Executor executor) {
        this.executor = executor;
        this.application = application;
        apiInterface= APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
        LearnDatabase database= LearnDatabase.getInstance(application);
        categoryDao=database.categoryDao();
    }

    public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CategoryViewModel>>  getCategory(){

        refreshCategory();

        List<CategoryItem> items;
        categoryDao.loadCategoryItem();

        items=categoryDao.loadCategoryItem().getValue(); // return null
        CategoryItem category;
        ArrayList<CategoryViewModel> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){

            category=items.get(i);
            CategoryViewModel categoryViewModel=new CategoryViewModel(application);
            categoryViewModel.init(category);
            arrayList.add(categoryViewModel);
        }


        arrayListMutableLiveData.setValue(arrayList);

        return arrayListMutableLiveData;
    }

    private void refreshCategory(){

        executor.execute(() -> {
            String lastRefresh=getMaxRefreshTime(new Date()).toString();
            boolean sliderExists =(!(categoryDao.hasCategory(lastRefresh)).isEmpty());
            Log.e(TAG,"sliderExist: "+sliderExists);
            Log.e(TAG,"lastrefresh: "+lastRefresh);
            Log.e(TAG,"hasSlider: "+categoryDao.hasCategory(lastRefresh).toString());
            // If user have to be updated
            if (!sliderExists) {
                Log.e(TAG,"in if");
                apiInterface.getCategory().enqueue(new Callback<List<CategoryItem>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<List<CategoryItem>> call, Response<List<CategoryItem>> response) {

                        executor.execute(() -> {
                            List<CategoryItem> categories=response.body();
                            for (int i=0;i<categories.size();i++){
                                categories.get(i).setLastRefresh(new Date());
                                categoryDao.saveCategory(categories.get(i));
                            }

                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<CategoryItem>> call, Throwable t) {

                        Log.e(TAG,"onFailure "+t.toString());
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    }

    private Date getMaxRefreshTime(Date currentDate){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(currentDate);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -FRESH_TIMEOUT_IN_MINUTES);
        return cal.getTime();
    }
   }
```

This is `xml` layout of item of `recyclerView`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data class="CategoryDataBinding">
        <variable
            name="category"
            type="com.struct.red.alltolearn.viewmodel.CategoryViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgItemCategory"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:imageUrl="@{category.imagePath}" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitleItemCategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@{category.title}"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

This is `CategoryDao` class:

```
@Dao
```

public interface CategoryDao {

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM course_table")
LiveData<List<CategoryItem>> loadCategoryItem();


@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void saveCategory(CategoryItem category);

@Query("SELECT * FROM category_table WHERE lastRefresh > Date(:lastRefreshMax)")
List<CategoryItem> hasCategory(String lastRefreshMax);
```

}

And finally I observe `MutableLiveData` in my Fragment:

```
    private void setupCategoryRecycler() {
    categoryViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CategoryViewModel.class);
    categoryViewModel.getAllCategories().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<CategoryViewModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable ArrayList<CategoryViewModel> categoryViewModels) {
            Log.e(TAG, "categoryitem: " + categoryViewModels.toString());
            categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(), categoryViewModels);
            LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
            linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
            CategoryRecy.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            CategoryRecy.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is here, right?

```
public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CategoryViewModel>>  getCategory(){
    ...
    items=categoryDao.loadCategoryItem().getValue(); // returns null
    ...
}
```

This is because your categoryDao.loadCategoryItem() method returns LiveData object. It means that method call will be executed in background thread. So when you call getValue() method the value yet null that moment.

To escape from this you can do two bad things.

**1.** Call loadCategoryItem() earlier, to have values later when calling getValue();

Your Repository class

```
public class CategoryRepository {
Livedata<List<CategoryItem>> items; // moved here
...

public void init () { 
     items=categoryDao.loadCategoryItem(); 
}

public MutableLiveData<ArrayList<CategoryViewModel>>  getCategory(){

    ArrayList<CategoryViewModel> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    List<CategoryItem> currentList = items.getValue(); 
    for(int i=0;i<currentList.size();i++){
          ...  
    }
    arrayListMutableLiveData.setValue(arrayList);
    return arrayListMutableLiveData;
}
}
```

Your ViewModel class

```
  public class CategoryViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public void init(CategoryItem categoryItem){
        repository.init();                          // added
        this.title=categoryItem.getTitle();
        this.imagePath=categoryItem.getImagePath();
    }
```

This can work but we have 2 problems. First is that still there is no guarantee that values will not be null. Second problem is that you cannot observe your item changes. Even tho you are returning arrayListMutableLiveData object, which is livedata, you are setting its value manually once, and its value will not be changed unless you call getCategory() again.

**2.** Second hack is load category items synchronously

```
    public interface CategoryDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM category_table") LiveData<List<CategoryItem>>loadCategoryItem();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM category_table") List<CategoryItem> loadCategoryItemsSync();
```

In this case your getAllCategories () and getCategory()  methods also should work synchronously.

Something like this

```
public void  getCategory(Listener listener){
executor.execute(() -> {
    ArrayList<CategoryViewModel> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    List<CategoryItem> currentList = items.getValue(); 
    for(int i=0;i<currentList.size();i++){
          ...  
    }
    arrayListMutableLiveData.setValue(arrayList);
    listener.onItemsLoaded(arrayListMutableLiveData);
}
}
```

In this case also we have the second problem -> you cannot observe your item changes.

I wrote this to better clarify the problem. *

**The real problem is that you trying use CategoryViewModel for data binding.**

Please use CategoryItem instead

I suggest to remove this two rows from viewModel

```
private String title;
private String imagePath;
```

Try to solve your problem *without parsing data* from List to ArrayList.

```
public LiveData<List<CategoryItem>> getAllCategories(){
        if (items == null) {
            items = categoryDao.loadCategoryItem()
        }
        return items;
    }
```

then try to use CategoryItem as data object

```
<data class="CategoryDataBinding">
    <variable
        name="category"
        type="com.struct.red.alltolearn.///.CategoryItem "/>
</data>
```

and try to change your adapter to make possible doing this

```
categoryViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CategoryViewModel.class);
categoryViewModel.getAllCategories().observe(this, new Observer<List<CategoryItem >>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<CategoryItem > categoryItems) {
            categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(), categoryItems);
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I myself try last solution.But I had a small mistake and i receive a `NullPointException` error. As @Kishore Jethava pointed, I'm trying to load data from the wrong table `course_table` and It should be `category_table`.

Comment: Changed table name in my answer as well. Happy to help ))

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use a trasnformation?

```
//this is returned to the observer in setupCategoryRecycler()
return Transformations.switchMap(repository.getCategory()) { result -> 
    //do any other stuff you need here           
    allCategories.setValue(result)
}
```

A transformation can be use to convert one liveData into another. Check: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#transform_livedata

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to load data from the wrong table `course_table`

> @Query("SELECT * FROM course_table") LiveData>
>   loadCategoryItem();

It should be **`category_table`**

Answer (score 0):

Your `items=categoryDao.loadCategoryItem().getValue()` will not have any value unless you call observe on it.

Comment: My friend, in the `CategoryRepository` I set value for it: arrayListMutableLiveData.setValue(arrayList); You don't understand my Problem.

Comment: I'm sorry I was mistaken. I changed my answer.